# Insert 8 million rows file inside a mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a file containing a search engine query log having the following columns: id, timestamp, session, user, document, query, Activity.

A query can be present several times inside the file, I created 2 tables in my Mysql db:

Query:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| query            | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| interaction_freq | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Interaction:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| interaction_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| data           | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| session        | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| query_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| activity       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The first table saves each single query and in the second one I have the information for each row having a particular Query, referenced by query_id.
In the first table the interaction_freq (number of rows in the Interaction table having that query) is saved as well.

My file contains over 8 millions rows and 1.5 million of unique queries so I would expect, at the end, the first table to have 1.5 million rows and 8 million rows for the second one.

The problem is that the insertion phase is really slow. The process quickly inserts the first 150.000 unique queries but after it struggles processing the others. I'm using a cluster consisting of 8 8-core Intel Xeon nodes (32GB RAM) and 18-ish Avante quad core Xeon 2.4/2.66GHz (8GB RAM).

At the beginning the first table had the "query" field unique so I thought it could be the problem. I removed the unique constraints by checking the uniqueness inside the Java program inserting the rows. That didn't solve the problem. I tried to keep the process running for over 48 hours and it didn't reach 200.000 rows in the first table.

I guess there is a problem I can't figure out...

I'm planning to use xml files as a possible workaround but having all the information inside a mysql db can really come in handy...

Comment: Can you show your code that inserts into the DB?

Comment: What method are you using to insert? like csv?

Comment: Do you have an index on your table?  That can greatly slow down inserts over time.

Comment: Maybe its a caching or transactional problem. Do you commit or flush (if you use things such as Hibernate) your inserts? Otherwhise your session (or DB) might store all the changes to allow for a rollback of your inserts.

Comment: Given that your program didn't reach 200k rows within 48 hours, I suspect three things are causing the delay. First and foremost, your check for uniqueness might be in the way. Second, you could consider dropping the indices and re-create them at the end of the program. Last, as mention above, think about transactions. One way to approach is to use batches. Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: I pasted my code here: http://pastebin.com/A8BJtXXW.
As you can see it's a pretty long class. It uses an underlying code for the interconnection with the db but it works... if needed I can show it but it's composed by several classes.

Comment: Basically this class reads a plain file row by row. It checks if the row is good. After that it modifies the keywords column with some string manipulations and checks in a search engine lexicon/stop words list. When it is writing the row in the db it checks if the query was already present inside the HashMap query2id, if it's not it creates the query in the db and updates the Hashmap, otherwise it get the query and update the interaction frequency. At the end it inserts the Interaction in the db.

Comment: I have tried to remove the sql insertion part for checking if the problem was related to something else... without the insertion the task is performed in less than one hour.